# A map between two totally ordered sets is a homeomorphism if and only if the map is oreder preserving

Tags: general-topology, functions, order-theory

I'm a little stuck with this problem and I'd appriciate any advice or hint you could give me:

Let $(X,\leq)$, $(Y,\preccurlyeq)$ totally oredered sets and $\psi: X \rightarrow Y$ a function. Then:

$\psi$ is a homeomorphism if and only if for all $a,b \in X$ such that $a \leq b$ then $\psi(a) \preccurlyeq \psi(b)$.

i.e., $\psi$ is a homeomorphism if and only if $\psi$ is order-preserving.

So far in this direction $\Leftarrow$ I was able to prove that $\psi$ is continuous and injective. But I really have any idea about how to proceed in the other direction. Or if it's not true I haven't found any counterexample.

I really appreciate all the help you can give me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The map on the real line $x\mapsto -x$ is order reversing, and is a homeomorphism. A constant map is order-preserving (according to the definition supplied above) but is not a bijection.

Comment: Before you can speak of homeomorphisms, you need topologies on $X$ and $Y$. Which are those? If it's the order topology in both cases, then @Mirko's counterexample applies.

Comment: @HenningMakholm sorry you're right, the topologies over X and Y are the order topologies.

Comment: @Mirko thank you very much the example was actually very simple I was thinking in a more complicated function.

Comment: if a map is order-preserving (defined using strict inequalities, to exclude constant maps) or order-reversing, then it is indeed a homeomorphism. But the other direction is not true in general (perhaps it is true for connected order), but every bijection from the integers to the integers (or from the integers to the natural numbers) is a homeomorphism (as only discrete topologies are involved) and of course most such bijections are not (or couldn't even be) order-preserving or reversing.

Comment: @Mirko thanks, just one quick question ,is it necesary to assume that the map is surjective and order-preserving to conclude that is an homeomorphism?

Comment: A homeomorphism is by definition a continuous bijection so that the inverse function is also continuous, so you need to assume (or prove) that the map is surjective ... and there are examples that I didn't think of in my previous comments, e.g. if $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ of $f(x)=\frac x{1+|x|}$ as a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ which are order-preserving but not surjective, and hence not a homeomorphism. So you would also need to assume that the function is surjective.